# Spring Boot - Standalone Tomcat / External logback file ignored

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, logback

I have created a **Spring Boot** application with version **1.2.8** where I'm using an external Tomcat Container for deployment.

In the deployment archive `.jar` I have a `logback.xml` with default values as follows:

```
<configuration scan="true">

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-4p] %-4c \n\t%m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${user.dir}/logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
                <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - [%-30logger{0}] - [%-5p] -%X{traceInfo} \n\t%m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO" >
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Now in my external Tomcat I have my `application.properties` and `logback`in my `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` folder.

Since these files are already on the classpath. The `logging.config` property by default is set to `classpath:logback.xml`. So the logback.xml located there should be visible but it is ignored.

I have  also tried an absolute path

`logging.config=C:\\myuser\\tomcat\\lib\\logback.xml`

which is also ignored.

I'm trying for example to override logging level with the external `logback.xml` like this:

```
<configuration scan="true">

    <root level="DEBUG" >
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLING"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: In a way yes. But not with an external file. I used some properties and initialized the appenders with Java. Probably not the best solution.

Comment: Can you post some code? Or answer yourself here...

Answer (score 0):

In your project *source* ensure that logback.xml is in a classpath folder.

So if your project is a web project named **sampleweb** your logback.xml should go

```
src/main/resources
```

You should not have to configure tomcat externally.